Build Session Logic based on DateTime in Snowflake SQL
I'm trying to build session logic based on DateTime value for a group of columns (like Userid, DeviceId)
For a given userid, deviceid the session can start any time of the day(first event) and
I want to assign a unique ID for the start of session, Session need not to start at 01 /02.. hours but can start at first occurrence and after the end of previous occurrence.
 WITH CTEA AS (
    SELECT 1 AS USERID, 100 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 01:01:00' AS EVENTDATETIME UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS USERID, 100 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 01:02:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS USERID, 100 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 01:58:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS USERID, 100 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 02:01:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 01:03:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 01:04:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 02:05:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 02:06:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 02:01:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 03:02:00' 
    )
    
    WITH CTE_SESSION AS (
-- ANCHOR
    SELECT 
            UUID_STRING() AS SESSIONID        
            ,USERID
            ,DEVICEID
            ,MIN(EVENTDATETIME) AS  EVENTDATETIME
        FROM CTEA
        GROUP BY
            USERID
            ,DEVICEID
        ) T
    
    UNION ALL
-- RECURSION -- Facing issue here -- cannot use Aggregate/window functions in recursion
        SELECT
            UUID_STRING() AS SESSIONID
            ,FM.USERID 
            ,FM.DEVICEID
            ,MIN(FM.EVENTDATETIME) AS EVENTDATETIME
           FROM CTE_SESSION CSS 
        LEFT JOIN  CTEA FM 
            ON CSS.USERID = FM.USERID
                AND CSS.DEVICEID = FM.DEVICEID
        WHERE COALESCE(FM.EVENTDATETIME, GETDATE()) > DATEADD(HOUR, 1, CSS.EVENTDATETIME) 
            AND FM.USERID IS NOT NULL  
        GROUP BY 
            FM.USERID 
            ,FM.DEVICEID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_SESSION

I'm able to achieve with looping, I'm looking for more performant way (Self joins/ window functions).
Please help if anyone has idea on this.
Desired Result:
> USERID    DEVICEID    EVENTDATETIME     SESSIONID(ANY VALUE)
>     1       100   2024-05-02 01:01:00   200
>     1       100   2024-05-02 02:56:00   201
>     1       100   2024-05-02 03:57:00   202
>     2       100   2024-05-02 02:06:00   203
>     2       100   2024-05-02 02:07:00   204
>     1       200   2024-05-02 03:02:00   205


Please format your desired result as a table so that it is readable. Also, update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write so far

Sorry about that, Done.

Try using the TIME_SLICE function, here's an example:
WITH CTEA AS (
SELECT 1 AS USERID, 100 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 01:01:00' AS EVENTDATETIME UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS USERID, 100 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 01:02:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS USERID, 100 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 02:01:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS USERID, 100 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 02:01:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 01:03:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 01:04:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 02:05:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 02:06:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 02:01:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS USERID, 200 AS DEVICEID , '2024-05-02 03:02:00' 
)
SELECT USERID, DEVICEID, EVENTDATETIME
     , TIME_SLICE(EVENTDATETIME::DATETIME, 1, 'HOUR', 'START') AS TIME_SLICE_START
     , TIME_SLICE(EVENTDATETIME::DATETIME, 1, 'HOUR', 'END') AS TIME_SLICE_END
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY TIME_SLICE_START, TIME_SLICE_END, USERID, DEVICEID) AS SESSIONID
  FROM CTEA
 ORDER BY EVENTDATETIME, USERID, DEVICEID;


Thank you so much Michale Golos, but one issue with this,  As I mentioned , session can start at any time and ends at 1 hr from the start time of the session for a userid, deviceid combo. And the next session starts after 1 hr of previous start time. Session cannot be like strict 01, 02, 03 hours of the day. Could you please see if that is possible with Window function/Self-Joins (any other apart from loopinb)

Can sessions span days I.e. if there is a record at 11:30pm and one at 12:10am, can they be in the same session? How do you determine when your first session starts in any date range?

We can consider one day as date range..

So the earliest time in any day is the starting point, any time within an hour from that time is in the session, the next sessions starts with the first record more than 1 hour from the first record, etc?

Thats correct Nick

My solution can be length but by generating session id for each hour starting from the first event datetime to last event datetime for the same user and device, you can achieve what you want without using loop.
I am using recursice CTE for the same. I am not sure if we should call it a loop indirectly but works pretty well in such use-case.
with event as
(
    select 1 as userid, 100 as deviceid , '2024-05-02 01:01:00' eventdatetime union all
    select 1 as userid, 100 as deviceid , '2024-05-02 01:02:00' union all
    select 1 as userid, 100 as deviceid , '2024-05-02 02:01:00' union all
    select 1 as userid, 100 as deviceid , '2024-05-02 02:01:00' union all
    select 2 as userid, 200 as deviceid , '2024-05-02 01:03:00' union all
    select 2 as userid, 200 as deviceid , '2024-05-02 01:04:00' union all
    select 2 as userid, 200 as deviceid , '2024-05-02 02:05:00' union all
    select 2 as userid, 200 as deviceid , '2024-05-02 02:06:00' union all
    select 2 as userid, 200 as deviceid , '2024-05-02 02:01:00' union all
    select 1 as userid, 200 as deviceid , '2024-05-02 03:02:00'
)
, event_time_range as
(
    select distinct userid
            , deviceid
            , min(eventdatetime)::datetime as first_event_datetime
            , max(eventdatetime)::datetime as last_event_datetime
    from event
    group by userid, deviceid
)
, event_bucket as
(
    select userid
            , deviceid
            , first_event_datetime as start_range
            , dateadd(second, 3600-1, first_event_datetime) as end_range -- adding 1 hour (1 sec less) in the first event timestamp
            , (row_number() over (order by first_event_datetime)*100) as session_id -- generating random session id
    from event_time_range
    union all
    select bucket.userid
            , bucket.deviceid
            , dateadd(second, 3600, bucket.start_range) as start_range -- adding 1 hour from previous event timestamp
            , dateadd(second, 7200-1, bucket.end_range) as end_range -- adding 2 hour (1 sec less) from previous event timestamp
            , bucket.session_id+1 as session_id -- generating random session id
    from event_bucket bucket
    where exists(select 1 from event_time_range timerange 
                where timerange.userid = bucket.userid 
                        and timerange.deviceid = bucket.deviceid
                        and timerange.last_event_datetime >= dateadd(second, 3600, bucket.start_range)
                )
)
select event.userid
        , event.deviceid
        , event.eventdatetime
        , event_bucket.session_id
from event
inner join event_bucket 
    on event_bucket.userid = event.userid
        and event_bucket.deviceid = event.deviceid
        and event.eventdatetime::datetime between event_bucket.start_range and event_bucket.end_range
order by event.userid, event.deviceid, event.eventdatetime
;

event_bucket CTE generates the range of dates for each hour until it reaches the final event of the user with the same device. I am using 3600-1 to exclude 1 second from an hour since I see in the expected result you want event happened at 1:01 and 2:01 in different session.
If it doesn't give you desired result but seems close, feel free to tweak the code.

Thank you Mova for your excellent answer, this is one of the best we can achieve but the problem is the session id working good for the first set (1hr), from the second set onwards (if there are more sessions - hours) then single Session is having different Session IDs. Working on the fix on my side.

Also from second set onwards, data is getting duplicated.

One more point, from second session onwards, it is like you are checking on the next hour but the next session starts at the first occurrence of (userid, deviceid ) combo after the previous session end time and so on.. Sorry for the complexity and ambiguity.

@srinivasmunagala Sorry, I am not sure if I am following it properly. But based on the provided sample dataset, I believe it should work properly. Are you trying to say it is not working well on your real dataset? if that's the case, would you be able to provide another sample dataset at least close to your real-time data?

Sorry Mova , I'm not able to explain it properly. I just wanna get SessionStart from the CTE through recursion but Snowflake failing with NO AGG/WINDOW functions. Can you please help me with this, Putting the query as an answer

Hi Mova, I updated the dataset, please see if helps

@srinivasmunagala I think I am still missing something. I see the record with eventdatetime as "2024-05-02 02:56:00" in desired result but I don't see it in input (CTEA). Additionally, event happened at 02:06:00 and 02:07:00 are having a different session ID even though the device and user is same? what is logical thinking behind this?
